# twitteR help unable to authorize even with registering

Tags: r, twitter, authorization, unauthorized, roauth

I'm having trouble using the twitteR package, because even with following the registration stuff with ROAuth, I still can't do crap.  Here's my input/output

```
setwd("C:/")
download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem", destfile="cacert.pem")
cred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=HIDDEN,
                     consumerSecret=HIDDEN,
                     requestURL="https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
                     accessURL="http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
                     authURL="http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize")
cred$handshake(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl") )

registerTwitterOAuth(cred)
```

Which results in:

```
> cred$handshake(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl") )
To enable the connection, please direct your web browser to: 
http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorizeoauth_token=MNjWmBE7QzodHlK8yeyZC559iunb8urA8cGLamww
When complete, record the PIN given to you and provide it here:

> registerTwitterOAuth(cred)
[1] TRUE
```

But when I try and do something:

```
> rate.limit <- getCurRateLimitInfo( cainfo="cacert.pem")
[1] "Unauthorized"
Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall("application/rate_limit_status", params = params,  : 
  Error: Unauthorized
```

I still get the Unauthorized error.

What exactly am I supposed to do here?

Oh, btw, my sessionInfo() is attached:

```
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] plyr_1.7.1     stringr_0.6.1  ROAuth_0.9.2   digest_0.5.2  
[5] twitteR_1.1.0  rjson_0.2.12   RCurl_1.95-4.1 bitops_1.0-4.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.15.1
```

Comment: Have you loaded the ROAuth library using `library('ROAuth')`?

Comment: Can you paste your `sessionInfo()` into your Question?

Comment: Here's my sessionInfo()

R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] plyr_1.7.1     stringr_0.6.1  ROAuth_0.9.2   digest_0.5.2  
[5] twitteR_1.1.0  rjson_0.2.12   RCurl_1.95-4.1 bitops_1.0-4.1

Comment: Can you try with the latest version of `R`? yours is a bit out of date.

Comment: Updated.  Same message.

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem and I read the "Twitter Client of R" manual(http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/vignettes/twitteR.pdf) again.
I have just found the following paragraph in the Authentication with OAuth section:

"The first step is to create a Twitter application for yourself. 
Go to https://twitter.com/apps/new and log in. After filling in the basic info, 
**go to the “Settings” tab and select ”Read, Write and Access direct messages”.** 
Make sure to click on the save button after doing this."

Then I changed my app's permission and it just worked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue by creating a new app, adding my phone number in my Twitter settings, installing the newest twitteR package from github, and authenticating via httr with this command:

```
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key=consumerKey, consumer_secret=consumerSecret, access_token=accessToken, access_secret=accessSecret)
```