# Unauthorized access to twitteR API after registration

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have been following the script and instruction from several blogs [Twitter Authentication with R](http://davetang.org/muse/2013/04/06/using-the-r_twitter-package/) and [Using the R twitteR package](http://stathack.wordpress.com/2013/06/13/getting-started-with-twitter-in-r/) to access the twitter API.

```
library(twitteR)
library(ROAuth)

reqURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
accessURL <- "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
authURL <- "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
consumerKey <- "-----------------"
consumerSecret <- "-----------------------------"
twitCred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,
                             consumerSecret=consumerSecret,
                             requestURL=reqURL,
                             accessURL=accessURL,
                             authURL=authURL)
download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem",
              destfile="cacert.pem")
twitCred$handshake(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem",
                   package = "RCurl"))
registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)
testSearch = searchTwitter("#food", n = 10, cainfo="cacert.pem")
```

I have no problem registering, everything went fine till I start using the searchTwitter() function where it throws  me the following error.

```
testSearch = searchTwitter("#food", n = 10, cainfo="cacert.pem")
[1] "Unauthorized"
Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(cmd, params, "GET", ...) : 
  Error: Unauthorized
```

I have tried to solve the problem by looking at [TwitteR, ROAuth and Windows: register OK, but certificate verify failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916283/twitter-roauth-and-windows-register-ok-but-certificate-verify-failed) and [Twitter client for  R](http://geoffjentry.hexdump.org/twitteR.pdf) and a similar problem at [twitteR help unable to authorize even with registering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713073/twitter-help-unable-to-authorize-even-with-registering)

However, I was unsuccessful to resolve this problem. Any help is extremely welcome. Thanks in advance.

```
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_AU.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
  [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_AU.UTF-8    
  [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_AU.UTF-8   
  [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
  [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] twitteR_1.1.7  rjson_0.2.13   ROAuth_0.9.3   digest_0.6.3   RCurl_1.95-4.1
[6] bitops_1.0-6  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.0.2 tools_3.0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing exactly the same problem.

What fixed it for me was going to my app settings on https://dev.twitter.com/ and choosing "Read, Write and Access direct messages" for Access type - have you tried that?

Comment: Hi @Stephen,  I saw this answer on Stackoverflow. In fact the problem was solved when I created a new app, but there were no difference in the setting and the access type was set to "Read, Write and Access direct messages" for both app. Anyway, thanks for answering hope your app is working well.